# Can linear complexity O(20n) dominate polynomial complexity O(n^2/3)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Graph for an algorithm with a complexity of O(n^2/3) (**polynomial complexity**):

[image: polynomial complexity]

Graph for an algorithm with a complexity of O(20n) (**linear complexity**):

[image: linear complexity]

Order of Dominance for different complexity:

> O(1) < O(logn) < O(n) < O(nlogn) < O(n^2) < O(2^n) < O(n!)

**Problem:**
If I were to defined a order of dominance between the two algorithms above `n^2/3` and `20n`, I am confused as to which one will come first.

According to the order of dominance for different complexity, I see that **polynomial complexity** dominates **linear complexity**.

**Order 1**:

> O(n^2/3) < O(20n)

But from the graphs, we can see that for `O(20n)`, the growth rate of the number of operations over the number of elements is greater than `O(n^2/3)`.

**Order 2**:

> O(20n) < O(n^2/3)

I need some clarification as to which order among **Order 1** or **Order 2** is correct.

Comment: Fractional powers aren't in the polynomial class (as you have just determined)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be purely a [math.se] problem.

Comment: For n >= 1, n^(2/3) < n^(3/3) = n < 20n. Seems very obvious once you see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`O(n^b) ⊆ O(n^a) if b <= a`

`O(20*n) = O(n) = O(n^1)`

`O(n^(2/3)) ⊆ O(n^1)`

A few words about [polynomial time](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialTime.html) complexity

> An algorithm is said to be solvable in polynomial time if the number of steps required to complete the algorithm for a given input is `O(n^k)` for some nonnegative integer `k`, where `n` is the complexity of the input.

Thus, algorithms with `O(20*n)` and `O(n^(2/3))` time complexity both have polynomial time complexity. 'Linear complexity' is just a subcase of a polynomial.